# Is it possible to add items that you do not have to the Outfit Designer?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

If I see a good armor on the GTN that I want to put on my outfit but I don't want to pay a million credits for it, is it possible to use it as an outfit without actually having the item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you must have the actual item and drag the item to the outfit slot to equip it and obtain the look.

Once an item is equipped, you can discard the original but if you equip a new piece in that slot you will have lost the previous.